# Problem with complex analysis $\sup_{z\in \mathbb{D}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}|z-a_k|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be the vertices of a regular $n$-gon inscribed in the unit circle $\mathbb{D}$. Prove that
> $$\sup_{z\in \mathbb{D}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}|z-a_k|=2$$

The vertices of the $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ regular $n$-gon inscribed in the unit circle are distributed uniformly around the circle. This means that the angle between adjacent vertices is equal to $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Let's consider the complex numbers corresponding to the vertices $a_k$. Since the polygon is regular and inscribed in the unit circle, the vertices will be of the shape $e^{2\pi i k/n}$ for $ k = 1, \ldots, n$. Now consider the product $\prod_{k=1}^{n}|z-a_k| $ for $ z $ inside the unit circle. We need to find the supremum of this product. Let $ z $ be an arbitrary point inside the circle. Then $ |z| < 1 $. Note that as $ z $ approaches any vertex $ a_k $, the modulus of $|z - a_k| $ tends to zero, which makes the product smaller. The supremum will be achieved when $z$ is at the center of the unit circle, that is, $z = 0$. In this case, $ |z - a_k| = |a_k| $, and since each $ a_k$ lies on the unit circle, $|a_k| = 1$. Thus, $\sup_{z\in \mathbb{D}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}|z-a_k| = \prod_{k=1}^{n}|0 - a_k| = \prod_{k=1}^{n}1 = 1^n = 1 $

Can you tell me what the error is and why 2 doesn’t work?

Comment: $z=0$ does not belong to $\mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_1$, ..., $a_n$ are the vertices of a regular $n-$gon inscribed in $\mathbb{D}$, there exists $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\lbrace a_1, ..., a_n \rbrace = \left\lbrace e^{i\left(\theta + \frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)} \mid k=1, ..., n\right\rbrace$$
Let $z \in \mathbb{D}$. We write $z=e^{i\alpha}$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. We have
\begin{align*}\prod_{k=1}^n |z-a_k| = \prod_{k=1}^n \left|z-e^{i\left(\theta + \frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)}\right|&  = \prod_{k=1}^n \left|e^{i\alpha}-e^{i\left(\theta + \frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)}\right|  \\
&  = \prod_{k=1}^n \left|e^{i(\alpha-\theta)}-e^{ \frac{2ik\pi}{n}}\right|  \\
&  = \left|\prod_{k=1}^n \left(e^{i(\alpha-\theta)}-e^{ \frac{2ik\pi}{n}}\right)\right| \\
&  = \left|P_n\left(e^{i(\alpha-\theta)}\right)\right|  
\end{align*}

where $P_n(X)=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n \left(X-e^{ \frac{2ik\pi}{n}}\right)$. But $P_n(X)=X^n-1$, so one gets
$$\prod_{k=1}^n |z-a_k| = \left|e^{in(\alpha-\theta)}-1\right| = 2\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{n(\alpha-\theta)}{2}\right)\right|$$

Now it is easy to see that $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n |z-a_k| \leq 2$ for every $z \in \mathbb{D}$, with equality for $z=e^{i(\theta + \frac{\pi}{n})}$.

This implies directly that
$$\boxed{\displaystyle\sup_{z \in \mathbb{D}}\prod_{k=1}^n |z-a_k| = 2}$$